# php site not showing any errors but not displaying anything

Tags: php

i know very little php and have set up a copy of a site (db, sitefiles) in iis that has php installed. run the phpinfo.php page so i know php is running and working. when i go to the homepage index.php i just get a blank page, no errors!!!

any idea how i get to view errors or why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have ERROR_REPORTING set to E_ALL and display_errors to On in your php.ini ?

Comment: At the very top of index.php, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: how about you tell us what type of setup this is running on? IIS? Apache2? What version of PHP? etc, do you want us to guess?

Comment: And showing some code would help too...

Comment: You probably just missed a semicolon or something.

Comment: You could also have put an exit() or die() that you really forgot about. It happened to me.

Answer (score 4):

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```